# Как в приложении Java скачать изображение из интернета и поместить в нужную директорию?

Tags: java

Пытался сделать так

```java
URL url = new URL("http://xxxxx.com/img/logo.png");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("X:\\Users\\XX\\xxxxxx\\xxxx\\xxxxxx\\logo.png");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
rbc.close();
```

но получал
`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://xxxxx.com/img/logo.png`

Comment: Код 403 означает что чтобы скачать этот ресурс Вам надо авторизоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Например, во так:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://website.com/image.png").openStream();
Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("/path/to/image.png"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Не работает, получаю такой же Exception.

Comment: Вы получили ошибку с кодом 403 - Forbidden (Доступ запрещен).
Вы можете убедиться в том, что метод работает, попробовав скачать изображение, например, из гугл картинок.

В случае с конкретно Вашим ресурсом - наверняка, для доступа к изображению нужна авторизация.